# VUE onclick v-slot to run Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, v-slot

I don't know if this is possible because I didn't find the solution or I searched wrongly.
I would like a click on the template to just launch some function from methods eg. Axios

sd.vue

```html
<template v-slot:tabPanel-1> <!-- Click this run Axios -->
  {{ model.name.value }}
</template>
<template v-slot:tabPanel-2>
  {{ model.name.value }}
</template>
```

And this is component for tabs

AppTabs.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="TabsApp">
    <ul class="TabsButtons" :class="{'': variant === '',}">
      <li
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabList"
        :key="index"
        class="TabsSingle"
        :class="{
          'TabsSingleActive': index + 1 === activeTab,
          'text-white': index + 1 !== activeTab,
        }"
      >
        <label
          :for="`${_uid}${index}`"
          v-text="tab"
          class="cursor-pointer block"
        />
        <input
          :id="`${_uid}${index}`"
          type="radio"
          :name="`${_uid}-tab`"
          :value="index + 1"
          v-model="activeTab"
          class="TabsInput"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <template v-for="(tab, index) in tabList">
      <div  @click="clickCard(tab, index)"
        :key="index"
        v-if="index + 1 === activeTab"
        class=""
      >
        <slot :name="`tabPanel-${index + 1}`" />
      </div>
    </template>
      </div>
    </template>

     <script>
      export default {
       props: {
       tabList: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
         },
        variant: {
         type: String,
         required: false,
         default: () => "vertical",
         validator: (value) => ["horizontal", "vertical"].includes(value),
       },
       },
       data() {
        return {
        activeTab: 1,
       };
      },
   
       };
      </script>
```

Do you have any idea how in sd.vue component
When the Template was clicked it triggered some function?
Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: I think you must describe what is ```sd.vue```? Is that a component that should be used in ```AppTabs.vue```? So I could not see that you imported that in ```AppTabs.vue``` component. First you must import that and update your codes to get better answers.

Comment: Sorry,  In one tab it loads a list of certain items from the API, in the next tab it loads from the same api something else but I have to pass a different Body id with the post. And there must be several such tabs, which will pass different body id

Comment: There is no difference that what is your goal, ```To use a child component, we need to import it in the parent component```. Did you read [this part](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component) of Vue docs?

Comment: Thank you, I know that of course. What I wanted to do as usual was to do something around it, via the onclick method and the function call in one component. 
I split this into additional components and it now works beautifully :)